# Testing desktop apps in parallel using nunit + jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, nunit, white-framework, nunit-console

I have big task in work. I need to run my tests in parallel to reduce time of execute. At the moment i have around 150 end to end tests which are testing windows desktop app and web app (~1,5h) but i need to run it with 4 different systems which we support, so execution time went up to around 6h for all.

Runner for my tests is nunit, code is written with C#, and everything is stored in TFS. I need to create new project in Jenkins (Pipeline or other within i can achive my goal). I tried a lot of methods, but i don't know how to run multiple test on few VMs or RDPs (to have isolated desktop where i can use mouse and keyboard for each test). Did someone of you challenging same problem as i mentioned here and have some examples to try? I downloaded Parallel tests executor plugin for jenkins but don't have knowledge of how to use it with TFS repository.

Comment: why is this tagged selenium?

Comment: ...which are testing windows desktop app and web app... I'm using selenium to test web app with cooperation to this desktop app. I hope that somebody have experince with that kind of problem.